# Is my session management right?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

> **Objective**

To offer inventory management features for authenticated users only.

> **Problem**

When I fake a login using my jQuery login dialog, and click [Connect], without having input any credentials, the Javascript alert says that I'm authenticated.

When I navigate to an inventory section, I can see no administration buttons. That is fine, **but why does PHP returns the user as authenticated then?**

When I authenticate correctly, the Javascript alert still says that I'm authenticated, **but I can't see any administration button appear after a page refresh. What is wrong?**

> **Code Samples**

The site's entry point: **`index.php`**

```
<?php 
require_once "security/logout.php";
logout();
session_start();
$now = time();
$_SESSION["authenticated"] = false;
$_SESSION["expires"] = $now + strtotime("20 minutes");
$_SESSION["last_activity"] = $now;
?>
```

**`logout.php`**

```
<?php
function logout() {
    $sid = session_id();
    if (empty($sid)) session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}
?>
```

**`authenticated.php`**

*This file is used as `require_once` for every php file requiring a session to be set. A bit like using `session_start()` for every single PHP file.*

```
<?php 
require_once "security/logout.php";

$sid = session_id();
if (empty($sid)) session_start();

if (!isSet($_SESSION["expires"]) 
    || !isSet($_SESSION["authenticated"]) 
    || !isSet($_SESSION["last_activity"])
    || $_SESSION["expires"] < time()) {
    logout();
    $now = time();
    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = false;
    $_SESSION["last_activity"] = $now;
    $_SESSION["expires"] = $now + strtotime("20 minutes");
}
?>
```

**`login.php`**

```
<?php
require_once "security/authenticated.php";

require_once "data/data_access.php";

$userName = "";
$password = "";

if (isSet($_REQUEST["userName"])) $userName = $_REQUEST["userName"];
if (isSet($_REQUEST["password"])) $password = $_REQUEST["password"];

if (isAuthenticUser($userName, $password)) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);    
    $now = time();
    $_SESSION["authenticated"] = true;
    $_SESSION["last_activity"] = $now;
    $_SESSION["expires"] = $now + strtotime("20 minutes");
} else $_SESSION["authenticated"] = false;

// The line below is the server response reported by the Javascript alert().
echo $_SESSION["authenticated"] ? 'true' : 'false';
?>
```

> **EDIT #1** Added `data/data_access.php`

```
function isAuthenticUser($userName, $password) {
    $sql = "select password from jmsports.users where login = :login";
    $cnx = createAndOpenDatabaseConnection();
    $stmt = $cnx->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":login", $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    $isAuthentic = $result["password"] === $password;

    // Bool:strictBool only ensures that only true or false is returned.
    return Bool::strictBool($isAuthentic);
}
```

> **EDIT #2** Added the code which show/hide buttons on server-side.

**`inventory-section.php`**

```
// This line below states that my authenticated session variable is false.
file_put_contents("debug.txt", $_SESSION["authenticated"] ? "true" : "false", FILE_APPEND);

<div id="newButtonDiv" style="text-align: center;">
<?php if ($_SESSION["authenticated"]):  ?>
    <button id="newButton">Add New Item</button>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post data/data_access.php? Assuming isAuthenticUser() is in it...

Comment: Just edited my question with the `isAuthentic()` function contained within `data/data_access.php`.

Comment: =--edit- copied out to main comment - Sorry, SO doesn't like code blocks in the comments... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting way of doing it, try this...

```
function isAuthenticUser($userName, $password) {
    $sql = "select login from jmsports.users where password = :password and login = :login limit 1"; 
    $cnx = createAndOpenDatabaseConnection(); 
    $stmt = $cnx->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":login", $userName); 
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $password); 
    $stmt->execute(); 

    // get column count... if it's > 0, authenticate...
    $result = $stmt->columnCount(); 
    return ($result) ? true : false ; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for brining a better way to authenticate user. Now, my buttons still don't show up when entering the section.

Comment: where's the code that shows the buttons (or in your case doesn't ;))? also notice that on your index.php you are destroying sessions every time... if that's deliberate, cool, but normally you'd call session_start(); on every page, login when needed and log out when needed (e.g. when you visit logout.php)

Comment: I just updated with a code sample which is supposed to show/hide buttons.

Comment: Have you called `session_start();` at the top of inventory-section.php?

Comment: Yes I did. =) `if (session_id() == "") session_start();`

Comment: try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); exit;` to find out what's going on in your sessions

Comment: P.s. check out this comment in the manual saying session_id gives inconsistent results etc etc... He's using `if( empty(session_id()) )` instead of `== ''` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php#101734

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38753/discussion-between-will-marcouiller-and-scrowler)